# vagrant CLI hangs on Windows 10

Tags: windows, vagrant, freeze

I am using vagrant 2.2.5 on Windows 10 behind a company proxy.

All CLI commands hang.
Let's use `vagrant help` to illustrate my problem.

`vagrant help`
takes more than 30s.

```
Measure-Command {start-process vagrant -argumentlist "help" -Wait}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 36
Milliseconds      : 94
Ticks             : 360943091
TotalDays         : 0,000417758207175926
TotalHours        : 0,0100261969722222
TotalMinutes      : 0,601571818333333
TotalSeconds      : 36,0943091
TotalMilliseconds : 36094,3091
```

`vagrant help --debug` shows that it's hanging on

`DEBUG checkpoint_client: waiting for checkpoint to complete...`

and on

`INFO runner: Running action: environment_unload #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x0000000004b32910>`

I noticed that if I disconnect from the network (airplane mode, ethernet cable unplugged), it gets a lot better:

```
Measure-Command {start-process vagrant -argumentlist "help" -Wait}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 5
Milliseconds      : 14
Ticks             : 50147343
TotalDays         : 5,804090625E-05
TotalHours        : 0,00139298175
TotalMinutes      : 0,083578905
TotalSeconds      : 5,0147343
TotalMilliseconds : 5014,7343
```

It's even better if I configure a proxy:

```
$env:HTTP_PROXY="http://my.proxy.host:port"
$env:HTTPS_PROXY="http://my.proxy.host:port"


Measure-Command {start-process vagrant -argumentlist "help" -Wait}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 2
Milliseconds      : 24
Ticks             : 20249878
TotalDays         : 2,34373587962963E-05
TotalHours        : 0,000562496611111111
TotalMinutes      : 0,0337497966666667
TotalSeconds      : 2,0249878
TotalMilliseconds : 2024,9878
```

By comparison, in WSL (Windows Subsytem For Linux), it's a lot faster in all cases (not dependent on connectivity):

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:        19.04
Codename:       disco

$ time vagrant help
(...)
real    0m1.043s
user    0m0.500s
sys     0m0.469s
```

As vagrant is in version 2.0.2 in my WSL Ubuntu, I tested also with this version on Windows. I had the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was somehow the access to the network.
Vagrant's support explained in the [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11082) I opened that vagrant will regularly check for new releases to notify the user whenever there is a new one.
If network access is slow or hangs, then every command will wait for it, because vagrant will try until it gets an answer.
Only then, it will wait for a while before trying again.
To disable this polling, just set the [environment variable](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/environmental-variables.html#vagrant_checkpoint_disable) `VAGRANT_CHECKPOINT_DISABLE`.